# Angular. Getting wrong data from ngb-panel

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I use ngb-accordion in my app. I am trying to get data from every panel but when the first panel is opened click from the second panel returns me wrong data.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASM1m.png)

I think the problem is the event which raises when input file changes.

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-danths?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

I will be glad if someone give me a hint for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to note in your code.

1. Your *ngFor is at `ngb-accordion` which is creating a new accordion for every loop, instead of creating multiple panel within one accordion.

Fix: `<ngb-panel *ngFor="let data of datalist; let i = index">`

2. You are using the same label for all three panels, because of which your first panel is opening every time, regardless of which panel you are clicking.

Fix: `<label [for]="'image-input-' + i">` and `<input ... [id]="'image-input-' + i"`

3. The modal that opens after image selection has no knowledge of which panel it's getting triggered from. So, you have to use your `(change)="onFileChange($event, data)"` event/function to keep track of selected panel/corresponding data.

Then you can pass that selection from your modal to your `processFile(...)`

Fix:

```
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  selectedData: Data;

  ...
  ...

  onFileChange(event: any, data): void {
    ...
    this.selectedData = data;
  }
}

html:
...
<input ... (change)="onFileChange($event, data)>

...
...

<button
 ...
 (click)="processFile(imageInput, selectedData)"
> Done
</button>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvznk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)